# Is it safe to catch ImportError when trying to import optional modules?

Tags: python, exceptions

I usually see this pattern at least once in every Python project I work on.  For example, in a Django project, this is often added at the bottom of the base settings file:

```
try:
  from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
  pass
```

Also:

```
try:
  import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
  import json
```

This has always bothered me a little bit though; what if the module is imported successfully, but then it triggers an `ImportError` itself?  E.g., in the first example, the `local_settings` module exists, but then `local_settings` tries to import a non-existent module.

Is this the safest way to import an optional module, is there a better way to achieve this functionality, or does it depend on the context/usage (and if so, what are the guidelines to deciding when to use this approach)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should generally be assumed that the optional dependency you are importing can work on its own. There is little difference between trying to import a missing optional dependency and one that cannot be imported because a required *transitive* dependency is missing.

In other words, why would your program need to care about `simplejson` not being available because it is not installed, or because a dependency of `simplejson` is not installed? Either way you cannot use `simplejson`.

For optional dependencies, it is up to the package installer to ensure that a dependency is correctly installed, including transitive dependencies.

For something like `local_settings`, there is indeed a (small) risk that a transitive `ImportError` is masked. You can always log the caught `ImportError` exception at level DEBUG or similar to make it easier to review what might have caused the exception:

```
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    log.debug('local_settings failed to import', exc_info=True)
```

The `logging` package will include the exception information in the log for later inspection when you set `exc_info` to true.

Another option is to issue a warning with the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html), the standard library has a [`ImportWarning` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ImportWarning) for this:

```
import warnings

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    warnings.warn('local_settings failed to import', ImportWarning)
```

Comment: I suggest to use [ImportWarning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ImportWarning) which is mentioned in official docs alongside or rather than logging it.

Comment: @ErayErdin: that depends on the use-case. If the module is being imported as a performance optimisation you can argue that a warning is then just noise, it is certainly not a *mistake* as the documentation for `ImportWarning` suggests.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally safe, assuming your modules are free of import-time side effects.

If an imported module raises any exception (not just `ImportError`) at import time, [it is removed from `sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading).  This means if any other code tries to import the module, it will not get a partially-initialized module.  Instead, Python will try to load the module all over again, and presumably fail with an `ImportError` all over again.

This can cause issues if your modules have import-time side effects, since those effects are not undone.  In particular, if the offending module *successfully* imports another module, the latter is not removed from `sys.modules`.  This particular side effect is rarely a problem, but some side effects can be more troublesome.